# Create PDF of whole UITableView for iOS version above 13.x

Tags: uitableview, swift4

I am trying to create PDF from UITableView for sharing data to outside.

Problem is what the code I have used is working great on device version below iOS 13 but on version above 13 it only render data which is on screen.
Now I am expecting to render whole UITableView for version above 13.x.
If anyone have suggestions please let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Here is my Code:

```
func createPDFDataFromTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> NSURL {
    let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height))
    tableView.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)

    let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width,height:tableView.contentSize.height) //height:self.view.frame.height)
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
    var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
    while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
     UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
     tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
     pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
     print(pageOriginY)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds

    //try saving in doc dir to confirm:
    let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
    self.ticksnew = getCurrentDate()
    if annDetail.announTitle != nil
    {
        FileNameToDelete=annDetail.announTitle
    }
    let fileName:String!="\(FileNameToDelete).pdf"
    let path = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName!)

    do {
        try pdfData.write(to: path!, options: NSData.WritingOptions.atomic)
    } catch {
        print("error catched")
    }
    return path! as NSURL
}
```